# Library not found when compiling C++ on OSX

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I am trying to setup my Mac (Mojave 10.14.6) to run C++ application and I am using Homebrew as package manager.

On my first very basic graphic application (using gtk) I received an error when compiling:

```
ld: library not found for -lgtk-quartz-2.0
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [src/mainDemo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/mainDemo.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

However, when running `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`, I see that `-lgtk-quartz-2.0` is present:

```
-L/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+/2.24.32_3/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/pango/1.44.6/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/harfbuzz/2.6.1/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/atk/2.34.1/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.16.0_2/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/gdk-pixbuf/2.38.2/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.62.0/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -lgtk-quartz-2.0 -lgdk-quartz-2.0 -framework Cocoa -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

The Make file is below:

```
find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(GTK2 gtk+-2.0 REQUIRED)


add_executable (mainDemo main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (mainDemo ${GTK2_LIBRARIES})
target_compile_options(mainDemo PUBLIC ${GTK2_CFLAGS_OTHER} -std=c++11)
target_include_directories(mainDemo PUBLIC ${GTK2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

I am looking to solve the problem but I cannot find the answer.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please show your CMakeFileLists.txt file. Please check your CMakeFileLists.txt there should be the following lines:

````
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GTK2 REQUIRED gtk+-2.0)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${GTK2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${GTK2_LIBRARY_DIRS})
ADD_DEFINITIONS(${GTK2_CFLAGS_OTHER})```

If they are not worth adding
````

Comment: I add the MakeFile in the question. Thanks !

Comment: I see one difference, you do not have target_link_directories / link_directories - it is he who adds the paths to the libraries. Please add it and show what it shows when cmake is executed and it is MakeFile

Comment: Thank you ! It worked adding target_link_directories(mainDemo PUBLIC ${GTK2_LIBRARY_DIRS})